# Android TextView formatting

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a TextView that is serving as a header for a ListView. I want to format it so that I have basically a title centered on the first line and then additional information on the lines following. How can I format the text/string to create this kind of formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) to specify you header. This way you can use separate XML layout to define the header.

You can then use gravity to be more specific with the layout

Comment: Good idea. For some reason I was thinking that the header would need to be something like a TextView but I guess it would work fine to create a LinearLayout and hand it that?

Thanks again.